# Metric organicGoogleSearchImpressions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to use the `google.analytics.data_v1beta` api to bring data from the `organicGoogleSearchImpressions` metric, however, I can't identify which dimensions are compatible with this metric, every time I try it gives me the error `google.api_core.exceptions. InvalidArgument: 400 Please remove landingPage to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible.`, can anyone help me by identifying which dimensions are compatible with this metric? my goal is to bring some dimension that can identify the page.

I am trying, for example, to execute the query below which returns this error:

```
request = RunReportRequest(
         property="properties/" + view_id,
         dimensions=[
             Dimension(name="date"),
             Dimension(name="landingPage"),
         ],
         metrics=[
             Metric(name="organicGoogleSearchClicks"),
             Metric(name="organicGoogleSearchImpressions"),
         ],
         date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)],
     )

     response = analytics.run_report(request)
```